# How do I calculate a profit for each month in MS Access?

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm quite new to access and I am currently in the process of making a database for my company.

I have a 'Jobs' table with these fields in:

- Job No.
- Year Initiated
- Month Initiated
- Company ID
- Job Description
- Amount Quoted
- Amount to Invoice
- Invoice Number
- Completed By
- Cost
- Profit

What I want to know Is what is the best way/ how do I calculate either in a form or query the overall profit for each month?

Please help, the database is really coming along, apart from this is well entruely stuck on.

Comment: I would write a query to do it but as i dont really deal with front end things like access it may not be the best way :/

Answer (score 0):

You want to find all rows matching a specific year / month, and add together all the profit entries for that month to get a total?

If so, try this :

```
select sum(profit) from Jobs where year = 2013 and month = 02
```

Or, if you want to retrieve this information for all months in one go, try this :

```
select year, month, sum(profit) from Jobs group by year, month
```