# Cumulative totals being doubled

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum

Hope this is a quick one:

I need to generate a single row containing the sum of all values where the ACCOUNT and MONTH are the same, in order to compare values between 2 systems.

However, when I simply select values, I get the correct amount, but when I apply a SUM() to the values, I get a doubling up.

Table structure:

```
ACCOUNT    MONTH    PC     VALUE
12110      201305   B1000  100
12110      201305   B1000  50
```

The correct values are returned by:

```
select 
    t1.[ACCOUNT] as [ACCOUNT],
    t1.[MONTH] as [MONTH],
    t1.[PC] as [PC],
    t2.[VALUE] as [VALUE]

from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2
on t1.ACCOUNT = t2.ACCOUNT
and t1.MONTH = t2.MONTH
and t1.[PC] = t2.[PC]

group by t1.ACCOUNT, t1.MONTH, t1.PC, t2.VALUE
```

This returns:

```
ACCOUNT    MONTH    PC     VALUE
12110      201305   B1000  150
```

However, when I apply the roll-up:

```
select 
    t1.[ACCOUNT] as [ACCOUNT],
    t1.[MONTH] as [MONTH],
    t1.[PC] as [PC],
    sum(t2.[VALUE]) as [VALUE]

from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2
on t1.ACCOUNT = t2.ACCOUNT
and t1.MONTH = t2.MONTH
and t1.[PC] = t2.[PC]

group by t1.ACCOUNT, t1.MONTH, t1.PC
```

This returns:

```
ACCOUNT    MONTH    VALUE
12110      201305   300
```

Can anyone please help, as I've been staring at this for over an hour, and can't bend my head around what should be a minor issue?

Thanks.

Craig

*** EDIT ***

OK, full table structure:

```
CATEGORY    DATASRC    CURRENCY    MONTH    VALUE                ACCOUNT    PC      FLOW
WF          PP         LC          201305   2588651.6800000000   12110      B1090   MV
WF          PP         LC          201305   -1288651.6800000000  12110      B1090   MV
WF          PP         LC          201306   1000000.0000000000   12110      B1090   MV
WF          PP         LC          201305   -500000.0000000000   12110      B1500   MV
```

In the above example, you see 2 values for the junction I need (the top 2).
The other rows have either a different MONTH (row 3) or a different PC.

What I am doing is to SUM the VALUES wherever the ACCOUNT, PC and MONTH are the same (rows 1 and 2 above).
The other columns (bar VALUE) are always the same.

The total of those rows should be 1,300,000.00.

When I SUM them (as shown in the first example), it returns 2,600,000.00

Is this enough to go on?

Thanks again

Craig

Comment: Can you show us data from both tables ? For me first query will not return `150` in column value.

Comment: i would have to agree with @Parado. If you show us both table schemas with the data from each it will give us a better idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you are doing a 'self-join' on this table, which is legitmately duplicating the results
i.e. returning (t1, t2) and (t2, t1).

Is there an index column (i.e. one with unique values per row)?  If so, you can add :

```
and t1.id < t2.id
```

to your join condition, to eliminate the duplicates

Comment: Thanks Graham.  I had to change it to read t1.id = t2.id, but it now appears to work.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure it's correct then.  If t1 and t2 have the same ID, then it is actually the same row ... so the join is not doing anything useful, you could just do a single select / sum / group by on the table.

Comment: you might be able to simplify to something similar to the answer from this question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789984/how-do-i-calculate-a-profit-for-each-month-in-ms-access/17791246#17791246